# Delete row from SQLite in android with costum listadapter

Tags: android, list, sqlite, adapter, delete-row

I would like to be able to delete one row at a time in my activity.

The activity is populated by a Costum list Adapter And I am also using a DatabaseHelper class.
I already made a deleteProduct method in the DbHelper.class. How can I call this function in my Adapater so that when there is a click in the imageView (there is an onclicklistener) the clicked row will be deleted?

**COSTUM ADAPTER:**

```
package android.ehb.be.verdoodt.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.ehb.be.verdoodt.DbFiles.Product;
import android.ehb.be.verdoodt.R;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Nick on 8/01/15.
 */
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Product> ProductArrayList;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> ProductArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_row_games, ProductArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.ProductArrayList = ProductArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_games, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        final TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_titel);


        // 4. Set the text for textView
        Title.setText(ProductArrayList.get(position).getProductnaam());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteProduct);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Adapter", "List Item Image Clicked");
                //DELETE HERE?

            }
        });

        // 5. return rowView
        return view;
    }
}
```

**DBHELPER CLASS:**

```
    package android.ehb.be.verdoodt.DbFiles;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Nick on 2/01/15.
 */

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //TELKENS JE DB AANPAST DIT OOK ANPASSEN
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

    //DATABASE NAAM
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GegevensManager";

    //GEGEVENS TABELNAAM
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "gegevens";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //ONCREATE AANGEROEPEN WANNEER DB VOOR EERSTE KEER WORDT AANGEMAAKT
    //CREATIE VAN DE TABLES, ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database created !");

        String CREATE_GEGEVENS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.GegevensData.TABLE_NAME
                        + "("
                       // + DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE + " TEXT,"
                        + DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_PRODUCT + " TEXT"
                        //+ DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
                        //+ DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE + " TEXT"
                        + ")";

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_GEGEVENS_TABLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.i("DbHelper", "Upgrade database");

        //VERWIJDER OUDERE TABEL ALS ZE BESTAAT
        //VERGETE VERSIE VAN DB NIET AAN TE PASSEN
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DatabaseContract.GegevensData.TABLE_NAME);

        //MAAK DE TABLE OPNIEUW
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //DOWNGRADE
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    public void clear() {
/*
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ALBUM_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ARTIST_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ALBUM_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ARTIST_ENTRIES);*/
    }

    //FAVORIET PROCUT TOEVOEGEN
    public Product addFavorietProduct(String productnaam) {

        Product FavorietProduct = new Product();
        FavorietProduct.setProductnaam(productnaam);

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_PRODUCT, productnaam);

        String Mijnproduct = String.valueOf(sqLiteDatabase.insert(DatabaseContract.GegevensData.TABLE_NAME, null, values));
        FavorietProduct.setProductnaam(Mijnproduct);
        return FavorietProduct;
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getAlleFavorieteProducten() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseContract.GegevensData.TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        ArrayList<Product> FavProducten = new ArrayList<Product>();

        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setProductnaam(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_PRODUCT)));

                FavProducten.add(product);
            }
        }
        return FavProducten;
    }

    public void deleteProduct(String productnaam)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //return db.delete(DatabaseContract.GegevensData.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_PRODUCT + "=" + productnaam, null) > 0;
        db.delete(DatabaseContract.GegevensData.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseContract.GegevensData.COLUMN_NAME_PRODUCT + "='" + productnaam + "'", null);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**FAVPRODUCTENACTIVITY**

```
public class FavProductenActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static DbHelper mijnDbHelper;
    static ArrayList<Product> FavProducten;
    static ListView listFavProducten;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("FavProductenActivity", "View Created");
        //Inflate fragment Lay-out
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(android.ehb.be.verdoodt.R.layout.fav_producten_layout);

        mijnDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        mijnDbHelper.clear();

        FavProducten = mijnDbHelper.getAlleFavorieteProducten();
        loadFavProducten();
        listFavProducten = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listFavProducten);

        String GekozenProduct = (String) getIntent().getStringExtra("productnaam");

        if (GekozenProduct == null) {

            Log.i("Gekozen favoriete product: ", "Geen geselecteerd");
            loadFavProducten();

        } else {
            Log.i("Gekozen favoriete product: ", GekozenProduct);

            Product gekozenProductToevoegen = mijnDbHelper.addFavorietProduct(GekozenProduct);

            Log.i("mijnDbHelper Add Favoriet product : ", String.valueOf(gekozenProductToevoegen));
            Log.i("mijnDbHelper Add Favoriet product V2: ", gekozenProductToevoegen.getProductnaam());

            FavProducten.add(gekozenProductToevoegen);
            loadFavProducten();
        }
    }

    public void loadFavProducten() {

        //ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter;

        if (listFavProducten == null){
            //DO THIS
        }
        else if (listFavProducten != null){

            /*adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FavProducten);
            listFavProducten.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("FavProductenSize = ", String.valueOf(FavProducten.size()));
            */

            ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, mijnDbHelper.getAlleFavorieteProducten());
            listFavProducten.setAdapter(adapter);
            mijnDbHelper.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.i("FavProductenActivity2","Product deletet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inline creating a default View.OnClickListener(), you may want to extend the OnClickListener to include reference to the clicked Product and the DbHelper

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ...
    class ProductImageOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        Product product;
        DbHelper dbHelper;      

        public ProductImageOnClickListener(Product product, DbHelper dbHelper) {
            this.product = product;
            this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Call delete here with the reference of product and dbhelper
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can set the ProductImageOnClickListener to the imageView.